# Liquibase diff functionality

Tags: database, oracle, maven, devops, liquibase

..so I was warming up to Liquibase and struggling to get the *liquibase diff* functionality working. I hope I could use this forum to get some help.

**Problem Description**

I have a updated my Dev DB with changeset1 and changeset2, while Prod DB has been updated with changeset1 only. Using the SQL developer UI, I can see the tables corresponding to changeset1 created on Dev and Prod, while the ones corresponding to changeset2 is not in Prod DB. So far, this is on expected lines.

However, when I execute a *liquibase diff* on Prod, referencing the Dev DB, I expect to see differences (changeset2). However, I don't see the changes listed out in the Liquibase output - and hence this post. Where could I be going wrong?

Please note, I am using dockerised instances of Oracle and have 2 docker-db instances mimicking a Dev and Prod environment respectively.

Maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jenkov</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
              <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
              <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <dropFirst>false</dropFirst>
              <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-dev.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>update</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <dropFirst>false</dropFirst>
              <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-prod.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>update</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

liquibase-dev.properties

```
changeLogFile: src\/main\/resources\/liquibase\/dbchangelog.xml
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
username: system
password:
verbose: true
referenceUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
referenceUsername: system
referencePassword:
```

liquibase-prod.properties

```
changeLogFile: src\/main\/resources\/liquibase\/dbchangelog.xml
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523/xe
username: system
password:
verbose: true
referenceUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
referenceUsername: system
referencePassword:
```

dbchangelog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
        <changeSet id="2" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department2">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Command executed

```
mvn liquibase:diff -Pprod
```

Liquibase output

```
$ mvn liquibase:diff -Pprod
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.jenkov:hello-world >-----------------------
[INFO] Building hello-world 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.7:diff (default-cli) @ hello-world ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] there are no resolved artifacts for the Maven project.
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-prod.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Liquibase Community 3.8.7 by Datical
[INFO] Starting Liquibase at Fri, 20 Mar 2020 23:35:03 NZDT (version 3.8.7 #55 built at Mon Feb 24 03:04:51 UTC 2020)
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-prod.properties for changeLog parameters
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523/xe
[INFO] there are no resolved artifacts for the Maven project.
[INFO] there are no resolved artifacts for the Maven project.
[INFO] Performing Diff on database SYSTEM @ jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523/xe (Default Schema: SYSTEM)

Diff Results:
Reference Database: SYSTEM @ jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe (Default Schema: SYSTEM)
Comparison Database: SYSTEM @ jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523/xe (Default Schema: SYSTEM)
Compared Schemas: SYSTEM
Product Name: EQUAL
Product Version: EQUAL
Missing Catalog(s): NONE
Unexpected Catalog(s): NONE
Changed Catalog(s): NONE
Missing Column(s): NONE
Unexpected Column(s): NONE
Changed Column(s): NONE
Missing Foreign Key(s): NONE
Unexpected Foreign Key(s): NONE
Changed Foreign Key(s): NONE
Missing Index(s): NONE
Unexpected Index(s): NONE
Changed Index(s): NONE
Missing Primary Key(s): NONE
Unexpected Primary Key(s): NONE
Changed Primary Key(s): NONE
Missing Sequence(s): NONE
Unexpected Sequence(s): NONE
Changed Sequence(s): NONE
Missing Table(s): NONE
Unexpected Table(s): NONE
Changed Table(s): NONE
Missing Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Unexpected Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Changed Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Missing View(s): NONE
Unexpected View(s): NONE
Changed View(s): NONE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.087 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-20T23:35:03+13:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi mmukhe, 

Sorry if this answer comes a bit late, could you try and run liquibase diff directly from the command line?  Would like to see if this is an issue with liquibase and its configuration before moving onto maven and all its config files.